after move php web to new host 500 Internal Server Error
I have a PHP website connected to a database, and it was working well until I moved the entire site folder to a new host.. The site did not work and gave me a message:
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
It's mostly related to the .htaccess file, which when I delete it gives me an error message 404
Please help me ...
Knowing that what is in the .htaccess file:
RewriteEngine on
# directory browsing
Options All-Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
php_flag output_buffering on

It's mostly related to the .htaccess file, which when I delete it gives me an error message 404
I need your opinions on how to solve the problem so that the web works on the new hosting

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
